# MapOverlay like as PopUp

Tags: android

friends. I want draw MapOverlay like as PopUp Menu same as in this image. How I can do this.[image: PopUp in MapOverlay]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use or refer to my MapViewBalloons project which I created for this purpose: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

Answer (score 1):

Refer to Commonsguy example, you can use it as a [reference](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Maps/EvenNooerYawk/src/com/commonsware/android/maps/NooYawk.java)

Comment: Beaten to the punch :) You use a series of itemized overlays and items and, if you choose, can overload drawing methods to get custom look and feel.

Comment: is it display Triangle below popup..?

Comment: @Nick ah its ok, i'll give you a couple of upvotes instead :)