# get data from ballon on ballon tap from google map

Tags: android

I had shown latitudes and longitudes in Google map when i click marker it display a balloon on which gallery name and address are written 
I want when I click on balloon that gallery name are fetched how to achieve this below is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenballon);
    itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable1, mapView);
    drawable2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blueballon);
    itemizedOverlay2 = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable2, mapView);
    drawable3 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redballon);
    itemizedOverlay3 = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable3, mapView);

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
            if(sitesList.getType().get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Centros Culturales"))
            {

         name = sitesList.getLatitude().get(i);
         name1 = sitesList.getLongitude().get(i);
        Log.i("centos culturales lat" + i,name);
        Log.i("culturarls longitiitude"+i,name1);
        point = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(name) * 1E6),
                    (int) (Double.parseDouble(name1) * 1E6));
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, sitesList.getGalleryname().get(i), 
                             sitesList.getAddress().get(i));
                     itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
    }
    }
for(int i=0;i<sitesList.getLatitude().size();i++)
        {
                if(sitesList.getType().get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Centros Culturales"))
                {

             name = sitesList.getLatitude().get(i);
             name1 = sitesList.getLongitude().get(i);
            Log.i("centos culturales lat" + i,name);
            Log.i("culturarls longitiitude"+i,name1);
            point = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(name) * 1E6),
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(name1) * 1E6));
            OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, sitesList.getGalleryname().get(i), 
                                 sitesList.getAddress().get(i));
                         itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
        }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<sitesList.getLatitude().size();i++)
        {
                if(sitesList.getType().get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Residencias"))
                {

             name = sitesList.getLatitude().get(i);
             name1 = sitesList.getLongitude().get(i);
            Log.i("residencias latitute" + i,name);
             Log.i("residencias longitiitude"+i,name1);
             point3 = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(name) * 1E6),
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(name1) * 1E6));
                         OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point3,        sitesList.getGalleryname().get(i), 
                                 sitesList.getAddress().get(i));
                         itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(overlayItem);
        }
        }
                mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);
**//actuaaly i show lat long in google map according to "gallery type"..so here how to get data on tap of baloon...??????**
               @Override
        protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {


    for(int i=0;i<sitesList.getLatitude().size();i++)
                    {
                            if(sitesList.getType().get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Centros Culturales"))
                            {

                                  array_galleryname1 = new String[sitesList.getGalleryname().size()];
                                  array_galleryurl1 = new String[sitesList.getImagesurl().size()];
                                  galleryname = sitesList.getGalleryname().get(i);
                                  galleryurl = sitesList.getImagesurl().get(i);
                                  array_galleryname1[index] = galleryname;
                                  array_galleryurl1[index] = galleryurl;



                            }

                 }
                    Toast.makeText(c,  array_galleryname1[index] + index,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

                    for(int i=0;i<sitesList.getLatitude().size();i++)
                    {                                    if(sitesList.getType().get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Residencias"))
                            {
                array_galleryname = new String[sitesList.getGalleryname().size()];
                  array_galleryurl1 = new     String[sitesList.getImagesurl().size()];
                                  galleryname = sitesList.getGalleryname().get(i);
                                  galleryurl = sitesList.getImagesurl().get(i);

                    array_galleryname[index] = galleryname;
                    array_galleryurl1[index] = galleryurl;



                            }



                 }
```

Comment: see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074178/mapoverlay-like-as-popup) you will defiantly get your answer...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486864/how-to-display-popup-on-tapping-overlay-in-android/4793288#4793288 This is the link where you can get you answer.
I hope this is help.

Comment: there are three main class file for ballon.. use it.. and in your main MapActivty add this line..Drawable drawable = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin2);
            itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, myMap);
            OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(gp, name,address);
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
            myMC.setCenter(gp);
            myMC.setZoom(16);

Comment: this exactly i had done but now problem is that how to fetch the data from ballon for showing in toast or use otherway...means my overlayitem  contain name and adress how to get it on tap on ballon,..pls explain plspls

Comment: i am able to display popup of ballon on click of marker but now qus is how to get data which is in the ballons?????pls explin??

Comment: mind actually i dont understood how to task performe onballontap() method for fetching the data save in ballon..pls refer to my code pls pls i will be greatly oblizefull of u..pls

Comment: @Override
 protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {
//  Toast.makeText(c, "onBalloonTap for overlay index " + index,
//    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  return true;
 }

Comment: pls refer to my code i had done this but value is being override becoze onballontap() i impose if() condition ,which data is coming i save it in an array and for second if() it again takes it from begining first refer to my code pls pls

Answer (score 0):

You have to override onTap() .
See this link. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: i had done more of things as on click on marker it display ballons on which i have filled some information now qus is how to get this data on tap on ballon ??

Comment: dear actually i am showing markers of diffrents color classified by "type"  and on overlay item i filled some information on it which is showing in the ballon now i want to get this value on click of ballon..