# How to put description in Map like this one?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to add something like this in my application(Google Map) when i tap on a marker:
http://www.android-software.fr/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Actelin5.jpg

How can we do this?
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this question about [draw MapOverlay like as PopUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074178/mapoverlay-like-as-popup) it is similar to your question.. I was got solution i hope you will also...

Answer (score 1):

1. On map page activity take geopoint for where you want to add marker,
2. used ItemOvelay for adding marker on tap.
3. pass address (geo points), marker drawable, in itemoverlay object.
4. in itemoverlay class use xml for popup window on tap of marker.
5. use map controller's animate to function on map activity page,

EDIT: For reference check [android-mapviewballoons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) and [map demo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Maps/EvenNooerYawk/src/com/commonsware/android/maps/NooYawk.java).